# SQL: How to filter by two lists

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a list:

```
ingredients = [
    {"name": "banana"},
    {"name": "egg"}
]
```

I have a list of inserted items:

```
insert_ingredients = ["banana", "egg"]
```

I want to fullmatch the ingredients list with the last last list. For example, I do not want to fullmatch it:

```
 ingredients = [
    {"name": "watermelon"},
    {"name": "sugar"}
]

insert_ingredients = ["sugar"]
```

I just want to fullmatch a entire list with another entire list, how can I do it using Flask SQLAlchemy?

I've tried:

```
filtered_recipes = base_query.ingredients.filter_by(name=(insert_ingredients)).all()
```

The result I want is an ingredient list with all inserted ingredients

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. What is the desired result for bananas and eggs ? Maybe include a complete example of what you do want, in addition to what you don't want.